# css3 animation only happening once

Tags: javascript, html, animation, css

I'm trying to make a box rotate through javascript/css3 rotate every time I click on it. It works, but only the first time I click on it. Each time after, I get the alert which means it's not a javascript error - but no animation.

Here is my simple page -

```
<script>
  function rotate( box )
  {
    alert('start');
    box.style.webkitTransform = 'rotate(360deg)';
  }
</script>

<style>
#box{ height:100px; width:100px; border:1px solid red; -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-out; }
</style>

<div id='box' onclick='rotate(this);'></div>
```

I figured there needs to be something I need to put after the rotate() to tell it to go back to the beginning stage so that it can rotate 360 again.

Answer (score 1):

I reuse a script i made previously. It should now support Mozilla too.

```
<!-- head part -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var angle   = 0;    //Current rotation angle 
var nbSteps = 30;   //More steps is more fluid
var speed   = 1000; //Time to make one rotation (ms)
var count   = 0;    //Count the nb of movement (0..nbSteps-1)
var element = null;

/**
 * Rotate the element passed
 */
function rotate(box) {
    if(count == 0) {
        element = box;
        rotateLoop();
    }
}

/**
 * Recursive method that rotate step by step
 */
function rotateLoop() {
    angle-=360/nbSteps;

    setElementAngle(angle);
    count++;

    if(count < nbSteps) {
        setTimeout("rotateLoop()",speed/nbSteps);
    }
    else {
        count=0;
        setElementAngle(0); //Just to be sure
    }
}

/**
 * Use for the rotation
 */
function setElementAngle(angle) {
    var rotationStyle = "rotate(" + (360-angle) + "deg)";
    element.style.WebkitTransform = rotationStyle;
    element.style.MozTransform = rotationStyle;
    element.style.OTransform = rotationStyle;
}
</script>

<style>
#box{
    height:100px;
    width:100px; 
    border:1px solid red;
    }
</style>

<!-- body part -->
<div id='box' onclick="rotate(this);"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Assuming you want it to be completely CSS:

Webkit transitions are currently being tested and are very rough. Especially for what you want to do. Since these are "transformations", and the style string is quite complex, it creates a nasty challenge.

The best thing to do it to reverse the rotation every other click:

```
<script>
function rotate( box )
{
  box.style.webkitTransform = box.style.webkitTransform == "rotate(360deg)" ? "rotate(0deg)" : "rotate(360deg)";
}
</script>

<style>
#box{ height:100px; width:100px; border:1px solid red; -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s ease-out; }
</style>

<div id='box' onclick='rotate(this);'></div>
```

Or youll have to deal with alot of dangerous coding, or javascript alternatives.

Comment: This solution will rotate the square in the opposite side the second time.
I would add the support for Mozilla with the MozTransform property and maybe add a extra variable to avoid click event while it's already in rotation.